# Получить файл .jpg из .jar

Tags: java

Пытаюсь получить jpg изображение когда сделал build файл jar, делаю так:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/help.jpg");
```

Сам файл находиться по пути: \src\main\resources\help.jpg

В итоге получаю exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Logs\CurrencyConverterBot-1.0.1-RELEASE-jar-with-dependencies.jar!\help.jpg (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:116)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.doWriteTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:134)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.writeTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:157)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.writeTo(MultipartFormEntity.java:113)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:160)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendHttpPostRequest(DefaultAbsSender.java:720)
at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendPhoto(DefaultAbsSender.java:212)
... 4 common frames omitted
```

Подскажите как получить файл jpg из jar в InputStream?

Comment: вы хотите получить файл из другого джарника? если да, то https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294594/read-a-file-from-inside-of-an-external-jar-file

Comment: А если в программе хотите получить файл из папки ресурсов то `ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("help.jpg")`

Comment: @Tsyklop Да, спасибо большое. Вопрос решен.
InputStream in = TelegramBotEngine.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("help.jpg");